# Statistics on the success of this site

Tags: discussion, statistics

I am wondering if anyone can provide statistics on how this site is doing as compared to others in the SE network at this stage in its life cycle.

I'm curious to see if the site is on par, or lacking in specific areas, e.g. visits per day, members, answered questions, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review

Shows questions per day, percent answered, users, answer ratio, and visits/day. Also lists what's expected by the end of the beta period.

Answer (score 3):

Yea, as the statistics show, the site has kind of become stagnant it seems.  There are also still not a lot of questions I can comment on just because I lack the appropriate domain knowledge.

We also keep getting questions that shouldn't be posted here because it seems they aren't sure what is supposed to be posted here.

I continue to watch on SO for questions that can be migrated.